# Span tag text with fixed width

Tags: html, css

What style attribute do I set to make sure the width in which '9' below is displayed is fixed to 4 characters,

```
<span>9</span>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please create a code snippet with what you have tried so far.

Comment: Your example is far too limited for anyone to offer assistance. Please expand your example using the code snippet tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your question, I have inferred that, you want to make the span tag wide around 4 characters. Well, CSS does provide the solution for this problem.

You can use the `ch` unit to set the 4 character width.

```html
<span>9</span>
```

Style:

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 4ch;
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

In CSS 1ch is equivalent to the width of "0" of the currently used font, in this case the span tag will have width of around four 0s. You also need `word-break: break-word` property, suppose if you have "99999" (five 9's without any space),if you did not include it, the 5th character will span beside the 4th character instead of the new line, causing the overflow of the characters in the span tag.

Also, if you want to enable it for the span tag make sure you are including the `display: inline-block` or `display: block` style for the span.